# 64-Bit Bootstrapper using WiX and Process count in Windows Process

Tags: wix, burn, wix3

I need the clarification for below mentioned questions. Can anyone share the details for this?

1. Three processes are running on setup installation created using Bootstrapper Application? What is the purpose of each process?
2. In Windows Processes list, Bootrapper exe shows as 32 bit process? Can we run this as 64 bit process? Whether 64-bit Burn available?